# How to sort an array when it is filled with numbers from a get method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, getter

Arrays.sort() gives and error of:

```
FiveDice.java:19: error: no suitable method found for sort(int)
   Arrays.sort(compNums);
```

If I take anything out of the for loop, it thinks thee is only 1 number or gives an error. What other sorting options would be usable?

```
import java.util.*;
public class FiveDice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        int compNums = 0;
        int playerNums;

        Die[] comp = new Die[5];
        Die[] player = new Die[5];
        System.out.print("The highest combination wins! \n5 of a kind, 4 of a kind, 3 of a kind, or a pair\n");
//computer
        System.out.print("Computer rolled:  ");
        for(x = 0; x < comp.length; ++x) {
            comp[x] = new Die();
            compNums = comp[x].getRoll();
           //Arrays.sort(compNums); <--does not work
           System.out.print(compNums + " ");
        }
//player
        System.out.print("\nYou rolled: \t  ");
        for(x = 0; x < player.length; ++x) {
            player[x] = new Die();
            playerNums = player[x].getRoll();
            System.out.print(playerNums + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

die class

```
public class Die {
    int roll;
    final int HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE = 6;
    final int LOWEST_DIE_VALUE = 1;
    public Die()
       {   } 
    public int getRoll() { 
        roll = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
        return roll; }
    public void setRoll()
        { this.roll = roll; }
```

}

Comment: `Arrays.sort` doesn't take `int` as parameter. In your code you are passing `int` value to `Arrays.sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use 2 arrays for the sorting. If you implement the `Comparable<T>` interface, your classes can be sorted by Java Collections API. In your case, `Die` class can implement `Comparable<T>` and provide a way for the Java framework to compare dice values.

Take a look at the Java API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

In your case:

```
public class Die implements Comparable<Die>{

    int roll;
    final int HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE = 6;
    final int LOWEST_DIE_VALUE = 1;

    public Die() {   } 

    public int computeRoll() { 
        roll = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
        return roll;
    }

    // I also changed this to store the value
    public int getRoll() { 
        return roll; 
    }
    public void setRoll() { this.roll = roll; }

    // This is the method you have to implement
    public int compareTo(Die d) {
        if(getRoll() < d.getRoll()) return -1;
        if(getRoll() > d.getRoll()) return +1;
        if(getRoll() == d.getRoll()) return 0;
    }

}
```

Whenever you have a `Collection` of Dies, like an ArrayList or LinkedList, you simply sort the collection itself. Below is a sample code.

```
ArrayList<Die> myCollection = new ArrayList<Die>();
myCollection.add(die1);
// more array population code
// ...
Collections.sort(myCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to implement Comparable to Die class , set value of roll in constructor of Die not in the getter method and your problem is solved.

```
public class Die implements Comparable<Die> {
    private int roll;
    final int HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE = 6;
    final int LOWEST_DIE_VALUE = 1;
    public Die() {
        roll = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
    }


    public int getRoll() {
         return roll;
    }        
    public void setRoll(int roll) {
         this.roll = roll;
    }

    public int compareTo(Die d) {
         return new Integer(d.getRoll()).compareTo(new Integer(this.getRoll()));
    }

}
```

now `Arrays.sort(Die[])` will sort the array of Die.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform `sort()` on `compNums` because it is a single value. You declare it as an `int` value, rather than as an array of integers.

Instead, you should make `compNums` an array, populate it with the `Die` roll values, and then perform a sort operation on the resultant array. I believe the following will achieve what you are after.

```
int[] compNums = new int[5];
...
for(x = 0; x < comp.length; ++x) {
    comp[x] = new Die();
    compNums[x] = comp[x].getRoll();
}
Arrays.sort(compNums);
// print results
```

Answer (score 0):

you must pass an array to the `Array.Sort(arr)` not parameter you must do something like this `Array.Sort(int[]compNums);`

and if you are using a anonymous type like `comp[]compNums` you must do it like this

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(comp[]compNums, new java.util.Comparator<Object[]>() {
        public int compare(Object a[], Object b[]) {
            if(something)
                return 1;

                return 0;
        }
    });
```